# jquery giving Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

so i am trying to load data with the help of ajax and it is showing me this error
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
and i think the main error is because of my php file i didn't think of any way to get my database values to my like.php file

jquery

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function validatelike(like)
{
    $.post("like.php",{like: like},function(data)
            {
            $("#echoresult").html(data)
            })
}
$("#newlike'.$mypostid.'").click(function()
        {
        validatelike($("#newlike'.$mypostid.'"));
        });
</script>
```

like.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];
    foreach($id as $msg)

}

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $getid=$_GET['id'];

}

$seepostquery="select * from posts where addedbyid='$getid' ORDER BY id DESC";
$seequeryresult=mysqli_query($connection30,$seepostquery);

while($seequeryrow=mysqli_fetch_array($seequeryresult))
{
    $mypostid=$seequeryrow['id'];
    if(isset($_POST['like'])) {

        $queryselector=mysqli_query($connection30,"select * from likes where postid='$mypostid'");
        $resultselector=mysqli_fetch_array($queryselector);
        $likes=$resultselector['likes'];
        $likedby=$resultselector['addedby'];
        $likedbyexplode=explode(",",$likedby);
        $dislikes=$resultselector['dislikes'];

        if($likes=="" && $likedby=="" && $dislikes=="")
        {
            $queryinsert=mysqli_query($connection30,"insert into likes values('','$mypostid','1','$dislikes','$msg')");
        }
        if($likes!="" && $likedby!="")
        {
            $queryinsert=mysqli_query($connection30,"update likes set addedby=CONCAT(addedby,',$msg'),likes=likes+1 where postid='$mypostid'"); 
        }
    };

    $queryselect=mysqli_query($connection30,"select * from likes where postid='$mypostid'");
    while($rowselect=mysqli_fetch_array($queryselect))
    {
        $countlikes=$rowselect['likes'];
        $countdislikes=$rowselect['dislikes'];
        $likepercentage=($countlikes/($countlikes+$countdislikes))*100;
        echo ceil($likepercentage).'% people liked this';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your PHP is creating a SQL injection vulnerability. Don't create SQL queries by string concatenation, use prepared Queries.

Answer (score 2):

Your php code is invalid in terms of syntax.

For example:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];
    foreach($id as $msg)
    //                 ^^^^^ loop has no body

}
```

The first `while` block seems not to be closed too.
Please use an IDE or some basic syntax highlighter to find such errors and reformat the code (Ctrl+Alt+L / Cmd+Alt+L in PhpStorm).